# How to get the file extension of the open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How to determine if the open workbook is a template (.xltm) or not. Basically, I have a template. If the user opens the template as (right-click >open) as .xltm file and tries to run a macro, I should prevent a macro from being executed.
If the user double-clicks the template, it opens as .xlsm, in that case I have no issue.

Can someone please help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

you can use below example to get extension of file

```
Sub extd()

Dim extFind As String
Dim sFile As String

        Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\aa\Desktop\devces.docx"


        sFile = Dir(FilePath & filename & "*")

        extFind = Right$(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, "."))

        MsgBox extFind
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this answer doesn't answer the OP's question. This is just a very generic code for finding extension of any file if we already have path/name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same. Since `ActiveWorkbook.Name` depends on Windows property `Hide extensions for known file types` (If u have them hidden `.Name` wont return the extension), u can use [`Workbook.FileFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840717.aspx). Returns an integer value, based on [`XlFileFormat enumeration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx). So, to check:

```
Option Explicit
Sub sample()
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat
    Select Case ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat
        Case xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled '52 xlsm
            Debug.Print "Its a workbook with macros enabled"
        Case xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled '53 xltm
            Debug.Print "Its a template with macros enabled"
        Case xlWorkbookDefault '51 xlsx
            Debug.Print "Its a workbook without macros"
    End Select
End Sub
```

`Debug.Print` Outputs to inmediate window, u can open it with `Ctrl+G` or in the view menu of the VB Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Code below:

```
'e.g. Active Workbook name = text.xlsx
Dim wk AS Workbook: Set wk = ActiveWorkbook
Dim fileExtension As String
fileExtension = Right(wk.FullName, Len(wk.FullName) - InStrRev(wk.FullName, "."))
'File Extension is now "xlsx" (without the .)
```

fileExtension will now contain the workbook type, which can be used as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getextensionname-method)

```
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.GetExtensionName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName) = "xltm" Then
```